# Char array prints random garbage in UDP client

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm making a simple UDP server/client and the code should do the following:

UDPCLIENT reads a line from the standard input in a loop and sends the data to the UDPSERVER.

An example of this is:

```
N4www.google.com
```

The first byte tells the server whether to send to the client the dotted decimal value (S) or the hexadecimal value (N) of the hostname (in this case www.google.com).

The second byte tells the server whether to send the IPv4 or the IPv6 address.

If I use S as the first byte, everything is fine and the client prints the dotted decimal value of the hostname.

Howerever, if I use N as the first byte, the server sends the right value(checked in wireshark) but the client prints some random FF values alongside the IP address in hexadecimal notation.

If anyone could look at the udpclient.c file and see where the error is, I'd be very thankful.

[udpclient.c](http://pastebin.com/EJrStiXY)

[udpserver.c](http://pastebin.com/DuJBKetX)

Here's the part of udpclient.c that's causing me trouble:

```
/* Recieve datagram from server */
if ((rcv_len = recvfrom( sockfd, rcv_buf, BUFF_SIZE, 0, 
                   (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &serv_len)) < 0)
            error("Problem s primanjem datagrama");

        /* If the value of first byte 0x00, print message */ 
        if (rcv_buf[0] == 0x00)
            printf("posluzitelj nije pronasao odgovor\n");

        /* If the value of first byte 0x01, print hex value from second byte */ 
        if (rcv_buf[0] == 0x01) {

            for (i=1; i<rcv_len - 1; i++) {

                printf("%X ", rcv_buf[i]);

            }

            printf("\n");

        }
        /* If the value of first byte 0x02, print dotted decimal value from second byte */ 
        if (rcv_buf[0] == 0x02) {

            memmove(rcv_buf, rcv_buf + 1, rcv_len - 1);
            printf("%s\n", rcv_buf);
        }
```

Comment: I'll add the obligatory copy-and-paste-your-code-into-the-question comment

Comment: It would be more useful to paste the _relevant_ code into your question.  See also [mcve].

Comment: @e0k ahhh,, almost nailed it

Comment: Added the code that's giving me trouble

Comment: Null terminator??  I haven't looked at the code/data, but that's what it usually is.

Comment: I found the error, I had to cast the values from the char array that I was iterating from into (unsigned char).

Comment: You server does this: `memcpy(addrstr, paddr, 4); strncpy(send_buf + 1, addrstr, sizeof(addrstr));`. That looks wrong as the `memcpy` does not produce a string in `addrstr` and hence the `strncpy` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were seeing the output like `FFFFFFCC 4F FFFFFFC5 FFFFFFC8` because in client side's print function, `printf("%X ", rcv_buf[i]);` `%X` expects its input to be `unsigned int`, while `rcv_buf[I]` is a `char`, so when the integer promotion happens, the sign bit got expanded. What you can do is convert the input to `unsigned` type, so that the promotion is done without sign bit.

```
for (i=1; i<rcv_len - 1; i++) {
    printf("%x ", (unsigned char)rcv_buf[i]);
}
```

Now it will print like

```
CC 4F C5 C8
```